# Spring batch JdbcPagingItemReaders cannot read the data again and finish immediately with read counts 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've a `JdbcPagingItemReader` which goes to Oracle DB and pulls records and writes to Mongo. The step itself is partitioned and I have `saveState` flag set to false. We don't really need to restart the job again. The reader is `@StepScope`d and the query provider too. However when the job is ran twice, the second time around it finishes immediately with read counts set to 0. I cannot see anything obviously wrong and there are no errors.  I tried to look into `batch_step_execution_context` to see if it's somehow reusing the previously ran `ItemReader` which ran to completion but I couldn't see anything in that table related to `ItemReader` per se. Any ideas on how to go about debugging this?

```java
  @Bean
  public Step load_A_Step_Partitioned(
      Step load_A_Step,
      OracleAnIdPartitioner oracleAnIdPartitioner,
      TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {

    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("load_A_Step_Partitioned")
        .partitioner("load_A_Step_Partitioned", oracleAnIdPartitioner)
        .step(load_A_Step)
        .gridSize(appConfig.getGridSize())
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step load_A_Step(
      JdbcPagingItemReader<SomeDTO> A_Reader,
      MongoItemWriter<A> writer,
      A_Processor A_processor) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("load_A")
        .<SomeDTO, A>chunk(jobConfigCommon.getChunkSize())
        .reader(A_Reader)
        .processor(A_processor)
        .writer(writer)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public JdbcPagingItemReader<SomeDTO> A_Reader(
      PagingQueryProvider A_QueryProvider,
      @Qualifier("secondaryDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {

    return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<SomeDTO>()
        .name("A_Reader")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .queryProvider(A_QueryProvider)
        .rowMapper(new A_RowMapper())
        .pageSize(jobConfigCommon.getChunkSize())
        .saveState(false)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public PagingQueryProvider A_QueryProvider(
      @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['ANID']}") String anId,
      @Qualifier("secondaryDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean providerFactory = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    providerFactory.setDataSource(datasource);
    providerFactory.setSelectClause(
        "SOME QUERY");
    providerFactory.setWhereClause(" anId = '" + anId + "'");
    providerFactory.setFromClause(" A TABLE ");
    providerFactory.setSortKey("COLUMN_TO_SORT");
    try {
      return providerFactory.getObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create A_QueryProvider", e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `where` clause of the query seems to be based on an attribute `ANID` from the step ExecutionContext. Where/When is this attribute set? Are you sure this attribute is present in the execution context when launching the second run? Because if that is not the case, it would probably explain why the query returns no results in the second run.

Comment: Thanks - I did find the issue, it was to do with Partitioner caching the keys. This meant even though the data set we're using was different from first time it had cached all the keys so when it was filtering, those ids did not exist in the new data set. But when I was following this through it wasn't clear how the item reader state is stored usually. Are they stored in step execution context table as well?

Comment: Since you disabled state persistence with `saveState(false)`, the reader won't store anything in the execution context. I think your partitioner should be step-scoped as well to avoid this caching (I guess currently it is a singleton bean and its state won't change from run to run).